# Rails / Stripe - taking multiple payments

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm building an events app using Rails and Stripe to handle payments. I've used javascript for my booking page in order to allow a user to book and pay for multiple spaces rather than just one at a time. The booking page allows for this as you can see here -

[image: Booking page view]

However on my Stripe dashboard only one payment has been taken for one space -

[image: Stripe payment]

How do I solve this so it takes the full payment indicated on the booking view?

Here's my Controller and view code -

bookings_controller.rb

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def new
        # booking form
        # I need to find the event that we're making a booking on
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        # and because the event "has_many :bookings"
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(quantity: params[:quantity])
        # which person is booking the event?
        @booking.user = current_user
        #@booking.quantity = @booking.quantity
        @total_amount = @booking.quantity.to_f * @event.price.to_f


    end




    def create
        # actually process the booking
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @booking = @event.bookings.new(booking_params)
        @booking.user = current_user

        Booking.transaction do

            @event.reload
            if @event.bookings.count > @event.number_of_spaces
            flash[:warning] = "Sorry, this event is fully booked."
            raise ActiveRecord::Rollback, "event is fully booked"
            end 
        end




        if @booking.save

            # CHARGE THE USER WHO'S BOOKED
            # #{} == puts a variable into a string
            Stripe::Charge.create(amount: @event.price_pennies, currency: "gbp",
                card: @booking.stripe_token, description: "Booking number #{@booking.id}")

            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        else
            flash[:error] = "Payment unsuccessful"
            render "new"
        end

        if @event.is_free?

            @booking.save!
            flash[:success] = "Your place on our event has been booked"
            redirect_to event_path(@event)
        end
    end


    private

    def booking_params
        params.require(:booking).permit(:stripe_token, :quantity)
    end



end
```

booking.new.html.erb

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" id="eventshow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2>Confirm Your Booking</h2>
        </div>
                  <div class="calculate-total">
                              <p>
                                  Confirm number of spaces you wish to book here:
                                    <input type="number" placeholder="1"  min="1" value="1" class="num-spaces">
                              </p>
                                <p>
                                    Total Amount
                                    £<span class="total" data-unit-cost="<%= @event.price %>">0</span>
                                </p>
                          </div>





                <%= simple_form_for [@event, @booking], id: "new_booking" do |form| %>



                 <span class="payment-errors"></span>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                      <span>Card Number</span>
                      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                  <label>
                  <span>CVC</span>
                  <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <label>
                        <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                        <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
                    </label>
                    <span> / </span>
                    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">    

               <%= form.button :submit %>


            </div> 

<% end %>
<% end %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.calculate-total input').on('keyup', calculateBookingPrice);

function calculateBookingPrice() {
  var unitCost = parseFloat($('.calculate-total .total').data('unit-cost')),
      numSpaces = parseInt($('.calculate-total .num-spaces').val()),
      total = (numSpaces * unitCost).toFixed(2);

  if (isNaN(total)) {
    total = 0;
  }

  $('.calculate-total span.total').text(total);
}

  $(document).ready(calculateBookingPrice)

</script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>');
  var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#new_booking');

    if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="booking[stripe_token]"     />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  };

  // jQuery(function($)  { - changed to the line below
  $(document).on("ready page:load", function () {

    $('#new_booking').submit(function(event) {
      var $form = $(this);

      // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
      $form.find('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);

      Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

      // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Do I need to add 'price' to my booking_params? I already have 'quantity' in there?

Do I need to add a 'total_amount' column to my bookings table? Or is it related to my Stripe action in the controller and the amount?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Stripe.order` and pass `items: []`, where you can pass `quantity`. In your case it will be one item.

Please check out [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#order_object) for more information

**Update**

Here step by step guide:

1. Login to `Stripe` account, create a `product` and make it `active`. This will be your booking. Save it.
2. When you inside the product, you'll see `Inventory`. Find `+ Add SKU`. Click it.
3. You'll see the popup window like this [image]
4. Fill in whatever you need to. In your case `currency`, `price` and `inventory`, perhaps `image`. `ID` will be generated automatically. Press `Add SKU`
5. Now you'll have `SKU` for this `product`. As you probably guessed already, you can have many SKU's for the same `product` and the `price` can be different.
6. Copy newly created `SKU id`
7. Now you can create `Stripe::Order` like this:

   ```
   response = Stripe::Order.create(
     currency: 'usd',
     items: [
       {
         type: 'sku',
         parent: 'sku_9AJ4OfKbdRuoGi', # SKU id
         quantity: 2
       }
     ],
     customer: nil,  # replace with customer id if needed
     email: 'michael.thompson@example.com'
   )
   ```

This is how your `response` would look like:

```
#<Stripe::Order:0x3ff36d37e2b8 id=or_18ryyuBq3wgBfJrxa44Jzm3T> JSON: {
  "id": "or_18ryyuBq3wgBfJrxa44Jzm3T",
  "object": "order",
  "amount": 19998,
  "amount_returned": null,
  "application": null,
  "application_fee": null,
  "charge": null,
  "created": 1473465868,
  "currency": "usd",
  "customer": null,
  "email": "michael.thompson@example.com",
  "items": [
    {"object":"order_item","amount":19998,"currency":"usd","description":"booking","parent":"sku_9AJ4OfKbdRuoGi","quantity":2,"type":"sku"},
    {"object":"order_item","amount":0,"currency":"usd","description":"Taxes (included)","parent":null,"quantity":null,"type":"tax"},
    {"object":"order_item","amount":0,"currency":"usd","description":"Free shipping","parent":"ship_free-shipping","quantity":null,"type":"shipping"}
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "returns": {"object":"list","data":[],"has_more":false,"total_count":0,"url":"/v1/order_returns?order=or_18ryyuBq3wgBfJrxa44Jzm3T"},
  "selected_shipping_method": "ship_free-shipping",
  "shipping": null,
  "shipping_methods": [
    {"id":"ship_free-shipping","amount":0,"currency":"usd","delivery_estimate":null,"description":"Free shipping"}
  ],
  "status": "created",
  "status_transitions": null,
  "updated": 1473465868
}
```

> When examining the response of any API call or webhook notification, use the `Order` object’s `status` attribute to verify the current status of the order and respond accordingly.
>
> - When an order is first requested, the resulting order object has an
>     initial `status` of `created`.
> - When an order is paid, `status` changes to `paid`. You should now fulfill
>     the order.
> - After fulfilling the order, update the `Order` object to change `status`
>     to `fulfilled`. Only orders in the `paid` state can be marked as
>     `fulfilled`.
> - If the customer cancels the order (through your site) before it’s
>     been fulfilled, update `status` to `canceled` which will refund the
>     payment.
> - If the order has been fulfilled and the customer returns the
>     purchased items, update `status` to `returned` which will refund the
>     payment.

Read [order guide](https://stripe.com/docs/orders/guide#managing-products-orders) for more details.

Now you should see new order in `Stripe's dashboard`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does that go in the controller?

Comment: Yes, instead of `Stripe::Charge.create` do `Stripe::Order.create` changing params as in api docs.

Comment: Does it need to go in as an array?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please accept it, if it helped you

Comment: Why do I need to change from Charge to Order.create? Is this the only way to accept more than one of something? You state that for quantity I should pass one item - should it be booking.quantity?

Comment: Stripe has very extensive and clear api documentation with examples. I suggest you to take advantage of it.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead if `charge = booking.amount * booking.quantity` , then obviously `quantity = booking.quantity`

Comment: I haven't got an 'amount' column for my bookings table. Do I need this before I can do the above?